# Injecting custom fields into JMeter report

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter test that is invoking an API (send API) in an asynchronous manner. The result of the invocation is then available via the other API call (results API). When I consume results, I do have a metrics about several phases of processing in the JSON response, which I would like to push into the resulting JMeter report.

I would like to get averages for that data, not just average times on the overall end-to-end test.

Is it something that can be implemented in JMeter?

Answer (score 3):

Injecting custom fields into .jtl results file can be done using [`sample_variables` property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)

Given you have 2 JMeter Variables, i.e. `foo` and `bar` you can "tell" JMeter to add them to the results file by either adding next line to *user.properties* file

```
sample_variables=foo,bar
```

or passing the values via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=foo,bar -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Once your test finishes you will see 2 extra columns in the .jtl results file holding the values for `foo` and `bar` JMeter Variables, hopefully getting [average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) for this data will not be a problem.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: the problem is, is it possible to set `foo` value from custom sampler (at run time)? if the value is to be predefined(no matter from jmx, or csv, or other sources in the client), then it might not be as useful as a dynamic metrics obtained from server when testing. I've tried `samplerInstance.setProperty(name, value)`  but not work.

Comment: Don't hijack the 6-years-old threads with comments which are absolutely unrelated to the original question. You should [ask your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead. As an exception: use [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class. For example like: `org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().put("foo","bar");` More information on this and other JMeter API classes: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: thanks, exactly what i have been looking for several days! unfortunately i'm now unable to  post question due to connection timeout to various js files (blocked from china).